# How to make Surface size to fit text content

Tags: javascript, css, famo.us

I followed this guide here

http://famo.us/guides/dev/layout.html

Most examples show the `size` either as `undefined` meaning it's max width/height or as fixed pixel number.

Is there a way to specific the size so that it wrapped and fitted the content text instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to set `true` as the value instead. For example

`size: [undefined, true]`